# I have never said + tense

Tags: tense

I know that combination of Present Perfect and Past Simple is okay in some cases but I need help now.

*I never said I wanted to do that.*

That is correct.

*I have never said I want to do that.*

This is also correct.

But what about this sentence:

*I have never said I wanted to do that?*

Please help!

Comment: Your sentences are correct. To me that would mean "Never before in the past have I stated that I wanted to do that".

Answer (score 1):

Because native speakers are not perfectly unanimous in their use of tense combinations, *I have never said that I wanted to do that*  can be understood to mean either of these things:

I have never said ...

"I *wanted* to do that"

or

"I *want* to do that".

If we use the past perfect, we can make it clear and unambiguous, at least to those native speakers who agree on what the past perfect means in such utterances:

*I have never said that I had wanted to do that*

would mean

I have never said ...

"I wanted to do that"

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence

> I have never said I wanted to do that

is correct and means

> *at* ***no time in the past*** *have I ever said I wanted to do that*